# side columns and text in the middle using inline style

Tags: css, css-float

I have html code and inline style applied to it, 2 columns with text links and vertical images on each side. in the middle i put the post text and content.

if the post is big, text will takes the whole page width after there are no enough images on the side columns to keep the text in the middle.

I want to keep the text in the middle of these columns.

```
  <div style="float: right; text-align: center;">

<p><strong>Version.V
   </strong></p>
  <p><strong> 999
    </strong></p>
  <p><strong>August 7, 2013</strong></p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">News</a>    </p>
  <p><a href="#">Updated
    News</a></p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Old
    News</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Posts</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Daily News</a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="#"><img title="here" alt="here" src="picture.gif" width="150" height="97" /></a></p>
</div>

<div style="float: left; padding-right: 1px; text-align: center;">

  <p><strong>Version.V
   </strong></p>
  <p><strong> 999
    </strong></p>
  <p><strong>August 7, 2013</strong></p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">News</a>    </p>
  <p><a href="#">Updated
    News</a></p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Old
    News</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Posts</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Daily News</a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="#"><img title="here" alt="here" src="picture.gif" width="150" height="97" /></a></p>
</div>
<div>


<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&rsquo;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br>
  <span id="more-208"> </span><br>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&rsquo;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&rsquo;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&rsquo;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&rsquo;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Text in the middle

the longer it goes down, it will be aligned to the left from the edge of the page, I want it to be in a box in the middle of the columns.

Comment: Sorry, I've read the question couple of times, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have 3 vertical images on each of the columns, what if i want to paste a lengthy text to replace <p>Text in the middle</p>? text will pass down the total images hight and text will be aligned to the left taking the whole page width. i want to keep the text width only for the space width between the columns, no matter if the columns have images on the sides or not.

Comment: [Here](http://jsbin.com/upoluz/3) is your problem, yes? You should re-design your layout. I'll post an answer.

Comment: [This](http://jsbin.com/eviqet/2) is a standard 3-columns layout. First, avoid using inline styles to make developing easier. Second, always follow the best practices.

Comment: I'm using it on wordpress post, have to use inline.

Comment: Okay, in that example, just write the external stylesheet as inline style.

Comment: Thank you, your example is very clear, it worked locally, i have to try it out now.

Comment: Would you consider accept this if I post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your p tag which holds your main content like so

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/R9UW5/)**

```
<p class="content">[main content here]</p>
```

### css

```
.content
{
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 150px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: It didn't fix the problem.

Comment: take a look at the fiddle - notice that the text in the middle remains within the center - even after it vertically passes the sidebar content

Comment: my inline code looks like this <p style="width:100%; padding:0 150px; box-sizing:border-box;"> and it doesn't work. same as without this style.

Comment: It works on a <div>. but the text is within the center from the left side only, it goes all the way to the end of the page from the right side.

Comment: if you're using firefox you'll also need to include this rule: -moz-box-sizing:border-box; (as I have included in the fiddle)

Comment: I'm using chrome and the page is wider from the right after using this class.

Comment: Does the fiddle work? If so, then maybe the code you posted in your question isn't the same as the code which you're working on. For instace, I noticed that the sidebar were both 150px wide is that the case?

Comment: Doesn't work, the code is the same and double checked that. It is a wordpress post html, am having problem on how to keep the text in the middle when vertically passes the sidebar content.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smVfC/)

Just add a style attribute to your content div with this:

```
style="margin-left: 150px; margin-right: 150px;"
```

Of course, that's considering that your side columns will be 150px wide (as I can tell for your images width).

Finally, as others previously stated, try using an external stylesheet, since it's more maintainable and easy to follow.

Good luck!